# Unable to get JSON response in Scalatra (using JPA for ORM)

Tags: json, scala, jpa, scalatra

I am using JPA for data modeling in Scalatra. I have a data model where in one class has a variable as an object of another class and that class in turn has a list of objects of a different class (a transitive relation). The 3 classes are as shown -

Entity XXX

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = “xxx_table")
class XXX(
     ...

    @(OneToOne @field)(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @(JoinColumn @field)(name=“xxx_id_2")
    var yyy: YYY,

     ...

    ) extends AuditableEntity {
    def this() = this(null, -1, null)
}
```

Entity YYY

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = “yyy_table")
class SomeSchema extends AuditableEntity {
     ...

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL))
    @JoinColumn(name=“xxx_id_3")
    @OrderBy("position ASC")
    @JoinFetch
    var objectTypes: java.util.List[ZZZ] = _
}
```

Entity ZZZ

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “zzz_table")
class ZZZ(
    @(Id @field)
    @(ManyToOne @field)
    @(JoinColumn @field)(name=“zzz_")
    @Column(updatable = false)
    var xxx: XXX,

    …

    @(Column @field)(name = "object_type")
    var objectType: String) {

    def this() = this(null, -1, null)
 }
```

When I have an object of XXX and convert it to JSON using Jackson, I see that I get the JSON content only for all the variables in XXX except the variable yyy. I tried changing the FetchType to EAGER and also tried doing a JOIN FETCH operation in the JPA -

```
SELECT ds FROM XXX ds JOIN FETCH ds.yyy
```

When I debug and look at the ds variable, I see that it has all the hierarchial content just the way I need; however, when converted to JSON, it content of the variable yyy is empty. Can you please suggest where I can have a look at to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using json4s with Jackson methods? If yes then you may have to add FieldSerializer for YY because DefaultFormat will not convert to JSON correctly.